# UIButton sizeToFit not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, sizetofit

This is my code :

```
let button_video = UIButton(type: .custom)
button_video.frame = CGRect.zero
if subsession.VideoUrl != nil
{   
    button_video.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: yAxis + 15, width: 300, height: 30)
    button_video.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 3, left: 28, bottom: 7, right: 5)
    if iVideoNumber == 0
    {
        button_video.setTitle(String(format: "Video #%i", 1), for: .normal)
    }
    else
    {
        button_video.setTitle(String(format: "Video #%i", iVideoNumber+1), for: .normal)
        }
        button_video.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Regular", size: 15)
        button_video.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        button_video.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button_video.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        button_video.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        button_video.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button_video.tag = iCount
        button_video.addTarget(self, action: #selector(CourseDetailViewController.loadVideo(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        let btnGradient = CAGradientLayer()
        btnGradient.frame = button_video.bounds
        btnGradient.cornerRadius = 6
        btnGradient.colors = [(UIColor(red: 174.0 / 255.0, green: 127.0 / 255.0, blue: 183.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor as CGColor), (UIColor(red: 78.0 / 255.0, green: 57.0 / 255.0, blue: 96.0 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor as CGColor)]
        button_video.layer.insertSublayer(btnGradient, at: 0)
        button_video.sizeToFit()
        view_scrollView.addSubview(button_video) 
    } 
}
```

The button however occupies the whole width of 300

Comment: are you using autolayout ?

Comment: @Lion : No, I am not.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting sublayer  with defined frame, and inserting it in your button. So sizetofit is working its size is equal to largest layes in button which is 300 due to size of gradient layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using multiple titles for different `UIControlState`, make sure to change the `UIControlState` before asking for `sizeToFit`.

In my `UIButton` I had to use multiple titles, one for `UIControlState.normal` and another for `.selected` state, I was expecting the result of `.normal` state, but the button was on `.selected` state.